# What's the plant name? It is climber or creeper plant..like money plant...help me finding its name...it has seven to five lobes

Tags: species-identification

[image]
It is climber or creeper plant..like money plant...help me finding its name.

Comment: Please add the location where you found it (country, state or city), and something on the habitat (forest, garden, wasteland in a city etc.). Only a leave is a bit difficult... Might be *Bryonia*

Comment: To add to @RHA's comment, when you add to the question, do it with an [edit] rather than in the comments. It may be useful to review the tag information at [tag:species-identification].